# BotComposer 1.4 scaling capabilities using custom C# runtime

Tags: botframework

I am using BotComposer v1.4 for developing my custom chat application.

In order to add some additional components, I am using the custom runtime in C# offered by the Botcomposer, which uses the Dotnet Framework 3.0.0, to run the application.

For lesser loads, less than 20 request per minute, the runtime works perfectly fine.

I am not clear on how well the custom runtime in C# offers scaling capabilities incase there is huge load on the server. As of now, I haven't found any reliable documentation which states that.

It would be very helpful if anyone can suggest or provide links for the documentation that tells me more about the scaling and the performance benchmark of the botcomposer runtime.

Comment: Out of curiosity; have you done the same tests with the runtime from Composer 2.0.0?

Comment: No I havent done the tests with Composer 2.0.0